# multiple objects not swinging, keep freezing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get these two objects to swing when I mouseover them. Independently. So, When I hover over box1 it will swing and then when I move away from it it will slowly stop swinging. However they both seem to just freeze.

Can anyone see why and help me fix it?

Here is my Js:

```
(function swing() {
    var ang  = 20,
    dAng = 10,
    ddAng = .5,
    dir  = 1,
    box = document.getElementById("box");

function setAng(ang,div){

if (div == "box") {

    document.getElementById("box").style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';

    document.getElementById("box").style.MozTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
    dir = -dir;
    if (dAng > 1)
        dAng -= ddAng;

    if (Math.abs(ang) > 0) {
        setTimeout(setAng, 1000, dir * (Math.abs(ang)-dAng))
    }

}

if (div == "box2") {

    document.getElementById("box2").style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';

    document.getElementById("box2").style.MozTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
    dir = -dir;
    if (dAng > 1)
        dAng -= ddAng;

    if (Math.abs(ang) > 0) {
        setTimeout(setAng, 1000, dir * (Math.abs(ang)-dAng))
    }

}
};


document.getElementById("box").onmouseover = function(){
    var div = document.getElementById("box");
    document.getElementById("box").style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
    document.getElementById("box").style.MozTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
    setTimeout(function(){
        setAng(20, "box")
    }, 1000);
}

document.getElementById("box2").onmouseover = function(){
    var div = document.getElementById("box2");
    document.getElementById("box2").style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
    document.getElementById("box2").style.MozTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
    setTimeout(function(){
        setAng(20, "box2")
    }, 1000);
}


})();
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z3s7v/1/

Thanks in advance guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in variables ang ,dAng, ddAng = .5, dir, which are used in every onmouseover function call, try something like that

```
(function(){

var box=document.getElementById('box');box2=document.getElementById('box2');

swing(box);swing(box2);

function swing(box) {
   var ang  = 20,
       dAng = 10,
       ddAng = .5,
       dir  = 1;

function setAng(ang){
    box.style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
    box.style.MozTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
    dir = -dir;
    if (dAng > 1)
        dAng -= ddAng;

    if (Math.abs(ang) > 0)
        setTimeout(setAng, 1000, dir * (Math.abs(ang)-dAng));
};

box.onmouseover = function(){    
    box.style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
    box.style.MozTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
    setTimeout(function(){
        setAng(ang)
    }, 1000);
}

};
}())
```

**EDIT**
I create simple web page for test this code outside jsfiddle, and it works, below is my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>        
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

     <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css"  />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box" class="box">
        <div class="pin"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="box2" class="box2">
        <div class="pin2"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {

            var box = document.getElementById('box'); box2 = document.getElementById('box2');

            swing(box); swing(box2);

            function swing(box) {
                var ang = 20,
                   dAng = 10,
                   ddAng = .5,
                   dir = 1;

                function setAng(ang) {
                    box.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + ang + 'deg)';
                    box.style.MozTransform = 'rotate(' + ang + 'deg)';
                    dir = -dir;
                    if (dAng > 1)
                        dAng -= ddAng;

                    if (Math.abs(ang) > 0)
                        setTimeout(setAng, 1000, dir * (Math.abs(ang) - dAng));
                };

                box.onmouseover = function () {
                    box.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(-20deg)';
                    box.style.MozTransform = 'rotate(-20deg)';
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        setAng(ang)
                    }, 1000);
                }

            };
        } ());

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey this seems to work when I use it in the JSFiddle but it doesn't when I deploy it to the website. I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: box is not defined. What is going on here?

Comment: Hi @MarkP, I make a test on simple html page (html code above), and it works, please check do You have javascript code after the containers "box1" and "box2"

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to set a "function()" in setTimeout()

```
function setAng(ang,div){

if (div == "box") {
    document.getElementById("box").style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';   
    document.getElementById("box").style.MozTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
    //document.getElementById("box").style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';

    dir = -dir;
    if (dAng > 1)
    {
        dAng -= ddAng;              
    }   

    if (Math.abs(ang) > 0) {  
        // Here you have forgot "function()"
        setTimeout(function(){
        setAng(dir * (Math.abs(ang)-dAng), div)
        }, 1000);              
    }

}
```

It works now in you fiddle for "box"